# Which approach consumes more resources : static or getter/setter?

Tags: java, memory, java-me, resources, hardware

Particularly in J2ME which approach consumes more resource : manipulating the `public static` variables or manipulating the `set()` and `get()` methods ?

Comment: I think you'll need to expand this question a bit, as to what kind of resources you mean. By the way, I think these two are not necessarily interchangeable options either, using static variables will most likely require you to design your code in a particular way. I'd suggest using getters and setters for all "ordinary reasons", just for the sake of simplicity

Comment: Even you ask for J2ME on Android there is a best practice: Do not use internal getter/setter. Explanation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html#internal_get_set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public static` field access would cost you less resources than `setter / getter` methods. If you are on a modern hotspot JVM, there will be minimal difference.

Answer (score 2):

That's impossible to tell, since it depends on the actual runtime environment. A JIT, AOT or Hotspot compiler may very well optimize away the potential method overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Using `get()` and `set()` methods may be a bit more costly than directly accessing attributes, (although the compiler or the JIT my optimize the method calls by inlining them) but anyway the difference is negligible. Also, in general you should not declare all your attributes as `static`, only the constant values.

On the other hand, using `get()` and `set()` methods is the the preferred option for enforcing the encapsulation of data, it's a good object-oriented programming practice. Not having those methods, forces you to expose the attributes to the outside, diminishing the ability of the class to hide implementation details and making future changes in the implementation harder.

Answer (score 2):

Introducing accessor methods significantly increases the size of class files. However:

- statics are evil
- prefer a bit OO, and encapsulate with behavioural methods rather than writing structs with pointless boilerplate
- you can probably find an obfuscator that will compact the object code for you

Answer (score 0):

set and get consume more than access to normal fields. You probably did not mean `static`.